# changed package name now a pop up window appears in app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I wanted to create 2 different versions of the app on the same tablet, the code is identical just a different package name, in the build.gradle file I wrote this code:

```
QA {
    applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
    debuggable true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

now when I open the app, on some screens, it gives me a pop up to choose which package name I want to use. How can I get rid of this pop up message ? What caused it ?

I was testing on a nexus 10 tablet.

Comment: Are you using build variants (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change package name in Android Studio.
[image]

Comment: but i need 2 different apps, as i stated

Comment: it will be another app

Answer (score 0):

you should leave the `buildTypes` unchanged and create `productFlavors` instead if you are just changing the `applicationId`

```
productFlavors {
    QA {
       applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
    }
    Dev {
       applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```